# chrome auto retry when sending ajax put request

Tags: google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

I know that chrome has implemented auto retry feature for loading page. But we currently find that Chrome also auto retries to send out duplicated request when Ajax put request is failed. And it only happens in Chrome. But there is no any document to introduce this.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: According to network log, it happens in this way: #1 client sends a http  ajax call #2 server returns http 204 (this is expected) #3 then server sends a RST ACK ( I didn't figure out why and when server sends RST ACK). #4 Chrome resend ajax call